# Getting "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden" Error Whatever I Do

Tags: c#, .net-core, webclient, http-status-code-403

I'm getting "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." error everytime i make a request to a website.I also tried every single header i saw on browser while making a request and i'm still getting the same error.What should i do to fix this error ? This is a console application on .NET Core 3.

```
        var url = "my-url";
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36");
        client.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"); 
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var html = client.DownloadString(url);
```

> Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: I think it can depends on url you paste. Maybe there are some tokens website use against bot activity or somthing

Comment: If there was , would i be able to see them in Request Headers while inspecting in browser ?

Comment: You should, yes. Are there no cookies being sent either?

Comment: could you try this instead of WebClient, `HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; } });`

Comment: @Xerillio Yes there is.I tried all of them but still it returns 403.

Comment: @ASLIM tried it,still returns 403.

Comment: did you try postman application to make custom web request to url, if postman gives same issue, it means that your issue is not related with your console application. (be careful to general cookies or auth type of postman while doing web request)

Comment: Is the url you use a third party url? Or do you call another service internally?

Comment: @SteliosGiakoumidis It's a third party e-commerce website

Comment: @MePengusta is it a public open api you are calling? Or is it a private one that you need some sorts of authentication to access it?

Comment: @SteliosGiakoumidis I'm just calling the website for HTML parsing

Comment: Debug Run into Console Application (not in IIS) then share with output of detailed error on the console. `secondly,  can you check whether this issue occurs in debug mode or not`

Answer (score 2):

The reason that is happening is very likely some web scraping countermeasures implemented by the site you target.

In order to by pass it you should try to impersonate a real browser as much as possible. That would happen by setting the necessary headers.

```
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
```

The above are some basic headers used by the browsers, try them and if it still does not work I would suggest to continue focusing on that direction.

**Step2:**

Visit this website from your browser using any sort of network proxy, like Fiddler, and intercept the headers on the request. Then mimic them in your application. That should work 100%.

Comment: Or you could, you know, respect the site's wishes and not scrape it...

Comment: I added every single Request Header i see in my browser to my code and i still got 403.I tried the same thing in Fiddler and somehow i got 200.I dont know what i'm missing.

Comment: If Fiddler is doing it, your code can do it too! Something small is slipping your attention. Triple check everything.

Comment: @MePengusta were you able to resolve your issue? I am in the same boat. Postman works but my application just keeps getting a Forbidden response. I added all the headers too, using WebClient, WebRequest, RestRequest. Security Protocol is set to TLS 1.2 and UseDefaultCredentials is true.

Comment: @Glenda were you able to resolve your issue? I am in the same boat. :D